# Flutter Error : The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error at snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : 'Loading...' how to fix this error thank you.

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: FlutterSession().get("token"),
              builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : 'Loading...');
              }),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include data type on `FutureBuilder<String>()` But also check others state like error.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: FlutterSession().get("token"),
  builder: ((context, snapshot) {
    return Text(snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data! : 'Loading...');
  }),
),
```